# Tkinter error to return __get attr__

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am a newbie to python,I tried a Gui Application,but its resulting in error like:

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\aqw.py", line 22, in <module>
    app = myproject(None,None)
  File "C:\Python27\aqw.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.button()
  File "C:\Python27\aqw.py", line 13, in button
    button = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Succedd !")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2106, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2027, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2000, in _setup
    if not master:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1826, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1826, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
```

Please help me to fix my code!

My code:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *

class myproject(Tkinter.Tk):
   def __init__(self,parent, master):
      self.button()
      self.checkbox()
      self.radiobutton()
   def button(self):
        #add quit button
      button = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Succedd !")                                                               
      button.grid(column=3,row=1)
   def checkbox(self):
      checkbox = Checkbutton(self, text = "Music", variable = CheckVar2)
      checkbox.grid(column=3,row=1)
   def radiobutton(self):
      radiobutton = Tkinter.Radiobutton(self, text="Option 2", variable=var, value=2)


app = myproject(None,None)
app.mainloop()
```

Please help!Answers will be appreciated!

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error, not just the last line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call super class' `__init__` method:

```
class myproject(Tkinter.Tk):
   def __init__(self, parent, master):
      Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self) # <----
      self.button()
      self.checkbox()
      self.radiobutton()
   ...
```

In addition to that, there's undefined variables `CheckVar2`, `var`.

Comment: If I provide just `Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)` without giving parent,master then to it works.Is that a good practice to avoid arguments other than self in super class method

Comment: @adsqwqwe, I updated the answer accordingly. Try `help(Tkinter.Tk)`. `Tkinter.Tk.__init__` does not take `parent`, `master` parameters.